# Ошибка с валидацей laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Ошибка (1/1) BadMethodCallException Method validate does not exist.
Скриншот по ссылке http://joxi.ru/ZrJVv3jFwdW4Br

Ошибка возникает при отправки формы

Контроллер

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::paginate(2);

        return view('admin.categories.index', compact('categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.categories.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
        ]);
        Category::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('categories.index')->with('success', 'Категория добавлена');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        dd(__METHOD__);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить:

```
$request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
    ]);
Category::create($request->all());
```

На:

```
$validate_data = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required',
]);

Category::create($validate_data);
```

Более детально можна почитать [здесь](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-form-validation-exampleexample.html)